# Javascript: how can an object be falsey?

Tags: javascript

Take the below code

```
console.log(navigator.geolocation == true);
```

[image]

As this is an object I believe it should be truthy, yet it always returns `false`.

Why is this?

Comment: because `navigator.geolocation` is not loosely equal to `true`?

Comment: Are all object not truthy? When I console.log I see an Object.

Comment: That's interesting; both `navigator.geolocation == true` and `navigator.geolocation == false` return `false`, when testing on my browser's console.

Comment: @seventeen An object is truthy yes, but being truthy doesn't mean that it is loosely equal to `true`.

Comment: truthy basically means *it converts to `true`* it does not mean *it is equal to `true`*. Do the conversion with `Boolean(navigator.geolocation)` or `!!navigator.geolocation` and you'd see it.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK because an object is not equal to `false`, either? It's been that way for...umm, literal decades now.

Comment: You can read it in the specs when abstract equality is true or false https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 This list is pretty much self explaining

Comment: So, summarizing, the object is still "truey", but, if instead of using it directly on the `if` clause, you do a comparison against `true` itself, the promotion process that precedes the actual comparison makes it so they aren't the same, resulting in a counter-intuitive, if logical, result.